# Too many redirects - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up redirect from www to non-www and from http to https using htaccess, but I'm getting "too many redirects" error. My htaccess is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

and some headers (XSS, CSP...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of reverse proxy that my webhosting uses.